# Is it possible to make Android Emulator appear as an USB device on my computer?

Tags: usb, usb-debugging, android-emulator

I know that I can't plug USB devices inside android emulator like a pen drive. But is it possible to make my emulator look like a regular phone connected to my computer? I launched the emulator, activated USB debugging and did `lsusb` on my terminal but nothing new appeared.

I'm asking this because I want to use Android Studio inside a virtual machine but I need it to launch apps on my Android Emulator which is parallel to the VM. If it appeared as an USB device then I could simply redirect it to inside my VM (it has this capability)

I already tried TCP but I don't know how to make it work for emulated devices: [How to do ADB over 'wifi' (actually in the same PC) for emulated device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/191491/how-to-do-adb-over-wifi-actually-in-the-same-pc-for-emulated-device?noredirect=1#comment248286_191491)

Comment: What's your host OS and your virtualization hypervizor? What's OS of your developer VM? (I guess it is some Linux.)

Comment: @v6ak I'm running Ubuntu 17.10.1 on both guest and host, and the virtualization is just out of the box android studio

Comment: Try the answers mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825169/android-virtualbox-shared-folders

Comment: @AbdelhafidMadoui as I understood, it'll just share folders. I'd have to install the apk by hand every time, isn't it? It'd not be the optimal solution. Isn't there a way to pass to use TCP or pass the USB?